# Issue after GCC upgrade C++

Tags: c++, perl, gcc, boost

**Current Code Base**
Os-Linux x64, have perl code, boost 1.42, GCC 4.4.7 and other dependencies as a part of project code. 
The build works fine.

**After Upgrade of GCC to 4.9.2**
We made a copy of existing Linux ec2 instance (which works fine) and upgraded its GCC to 4.9.2.
When we are trying to build the project, getting the below error.

```
webql/rt/bootstrap: Compiling main.cxx
webql/rt/bootstrap: @/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/gfilt -pthread -fPIC -DU_HAVE_NAMESPACE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_unix -D_BSD -fexceptions -fmessage-length=0 -I/home/builder/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/perl/core -DQL2_PLATFORM="al" -DJAVA_ARCH="amd64" -fvisibility=hidden -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/include -I. -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxml -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxslt -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/zlib -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include/linux -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux -I/mnt/usr/include -ggdb3 -O3 -DNDEBUG -c -o /archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/obj/webql/rt/bootstrap/main.o main.cxx

    In file included from ../perlapi/perl.h::,
                     from ../perlapi/Utils.h:,
                     from main.cxx::
    /archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/perl/core/perl.h::49: error: declaration of int setresuid(uid_t, uid_t, uid_t) has a different exception specifier
     int setresuid(uid_t ruid, uid_t euid, uid_t suid);

    In file included from main.cxx::
    /mnt/usr/include/unistd.h:: error: from previous declaration int setresuid(__uid_t, __uid_t, __uid_t) throw ()
     extern int setresuid (__uid_t __ruid, __uid_t __euid, __uid_t __suid)

    In file included from ../perlapi/perl.h::,
                     from ../perlapi/Utils.h:,
                     from main.cxx::
    /archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/perl/core/perl.h: error: declaration of int setresgid(gid_t, gid_t, gid_t) has a different exception specifier
     int setresgid(gid_t rgid, gid_t egid, gid_t sgid);

    In file included from main.cxx::
    /mnt/usr/include/unistd.h:: error: from previous declaration int setresgid(__gid_t, __gid_t, __gid_t) throw ()
     extern int setresgid (__gid_t __rgid, __gid_t __egid, __gid_t __sgid)

make: Leaving directory `/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/webql'
```

**Things tried**
Re compiled the boost 1.42 and other dependencies

**Expectation**
Even after trying several things the error remains same. perl.h is part of project code while unistd.h is a system file. Obviously perl.h is C code hence it cannot THROW exception as present in unstd.h function declaration.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is best to build Perl modules that require a compiler with the same compiler that built your perl executable. If you need to upgrade your compiler, consider rebuilding your perl executable from source.

Comment: Probably some C++ file failed to put `extern "C" {}` around an `#include` of a C header file.

Comment: What is `perl.h` used for in the project? Are you trying to build the `perl` executable or something else?

Comment: You include `perl.h` to use the Perl API. See [`perldoc perlguts`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlguts).

Comment: **@mob** - I already have the whole perl c code (headers files, c files) included in our project, which works fine with GCC 4.4. The current build was setup by someone else who has left the org. Now we want to use AWS API in our project for which minimum GCC is 4.9. When I upgraded the existing build server to GCC 4.9, i am getting the mentioned error. 
In simple words the current project is compiled successfully with existing GCC 4.4, but not with GCC 4.9.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland - whole perl source coce is being used in our project along with C++ and other dependencies like network related, sockets etc. In short our product uses perl internally to fetch data from internet, which is coupled with C++ code.

Comment: **@ aschepler** - Like I said current code is compiled successfully with GCC 4.4. This build process is quite old and working without any issue. Now we need GCC 4.9. After upgrade of GCC to 4.9, the existing code gives mentioned error. So don't think there is any missing identifier issue or file inclusion issue.

Comment: And thank you   **mob**, **aschepler** and ** Håkon Hægland** for your responses.

Comment: @RohitYadav Can you remove the ANSI escape characters from the shell output? Then it will be easier to read. Also include some more information about the file `main.cxx`. Can you also try to reduce the file `main.cxx` to the minimum code that still produces the error?

Comment: ** Håkon Hægland** - edited the shell output. The error points to different function declarations of setresuid and setresgid in perl.h and unistd.h. I have not made any changes in code. The same piece of code works fine in current existing build server having GCC 4.4. When I upgraded the GCC to 4.9 and recompiled the project, i am getting the mentioned error. In fact both files have same function declarations in GCC 4.4 also where it works perfectly fine. 
Main file contains 1400+ line of code which includes perl lib source code etc plus other stuff.

Comment: Did you try updating the version of perl you are using? Did you clean everything and rerun configure? The offending line is protected by `!defined(HAS_SETRESUID_PROTO)`, so you would need to investigate why that isn't defined.

Comment: `perl.h::49: error: declaration of int setresuid(uid_t, uid_t, uid_t) has a different exception specifer` : What is on line 49 of your `perl.h` file?

Comment: /* some versions of glibc are missing the setresuid() proto */

#if defined(HAS_SETRESUID) && !defined(HAS_SETRESUID_PROTO)
int setresuid(uid_t ruid, uid_t euid, uid_t suid);
#endif

/* some versions of glibc are missing the setresgid() proto */

#if defined(HAS_SETRESGID) && !defined(HAS_SETRESGID_PROTO)
int setresgid(gid_t rgid, gid_t egid, gid_t sgid);
#endif

Comment: Can you try and compile with `HAS_SETRESUID_PROTO` defined? `g++ -DHAS_SETRESUID_PROTO ... main.cxx`

Comment: Håkon Hægland  - You are bang on. this flag solved the problem :-)
I have used the following two flags, as the error was for two functions. 
-DHAS_SETRESUID_PROTO=1 -DHAS_SETRESGID_PROTO=1
my build completed successfully :-) Thanks a ton for you suggestions. Really appreciate it. 
My next target is to integrated AWS C++ API in my existing project. In windows it is working fine, would ensure that it works fine in Linux also :-) So keep a watch on me ;-) 
Again thanks a lot!!